# Selecting div prev image only

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that changes the fullsize image by hovering over the thumb image -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.thumbimage a img').on('hover',function(){
            $('.fullsizeimage a img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
        });
</script>
```

how do I set it up so that it only changes the fullsize image above it, and every other fullsize image?

I tried the following with no luck :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.thumbimage a img').on('hover',function(){
            $('.thumbimage a img').prev('.fullsizeimage a img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
        });
        </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CUZBa/19/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `row` is a parent element.

```
$('.thumbimage a img').on('click hover', function() {
    $(this).parents('.row').find('.fullsizeimage img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) will traverse the siblings of the element and not its ancestor..

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) in such cases

Try this

```
$('.thumbimage a img').on('click hover', function() {
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.fullsizeimage img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});​
```